# pause & shutdown quartz immediately

Tags: quartz-scheduler

When I pass over a request from the UI, assign the specific job `Pause` or `Shutdown`.
How could I make the job stop immediately?

For the method `scheduler.pauseJob(JobKey.jobKey(jobName));` in quartz will run finish this job, then it will stop. It takes me a so long time to deal with the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate more on the subject. Also `Thanks in advance.` are unnecessary at StackOverflow.

Comment: yeah, I want to pause the job immediately when get the command to pause.
but it seemed the exist method .pauseJob(JobKey) need to finish the particular job when started, not immediately. How could I make it.